# How set background-image for different screen variation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble with how to set different background images (or make responsive background images) for different screen sizes. My intention is to set 2 background images. First is for the size of a mobile screen and another of the size of a PC screen. I tried browsing the internet and watching tutorials on Youtube but it drives me no closer to what I want to happen. I am new to programming web applications and any help, tips and suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. Just in case someone's having a hard time looking for answer it's here.
Credits and thanks to the owner of this [article](https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/responsive-background-image/).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the simple procedure

```css
# Usual CSS for Big screens
.myClass{
  background-image: url();
  }

#for small screeens or whatever width you want

@media (max-width:768px){
.myClass{
  background-image: url();
  }
}
```